# "lighthttpd" should be a synonym of "lighttpd"

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[lighthttpd](/questions/tagged/lighthttpd) should be a synonym of [lighttpd](/questions/tagged/lighttpd), on Stack Overflow, as the former is either a nickname or a mistaken name for the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems reasonable. Done: there's a synonym going from [lighthttpd](/questions/tagged/lighthttpd) to [lighttpd](/questions/tagged/lighttpd), and I merged them so all the questions in the former have been retagged with the latter.